# Table Header in Google Charts loses background on scroll

Tags: css, charts, html-table

I have a header row in a google chart with text wrapping (which i know is the issue with the new api removing it) that is losing the background color when the user scrolls down.

When i have text wrap off, the header row background persists, but the view becomes unpleasant to look at because the table is now so wide and requires a horizontal scroll bar.

this is a good example of the problem. you will see what happens when you scroll down the records in the resulting table

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/VTK3g/5/

is there some way to define the css to keep that header row with the background color? Or any other way outside of this construct?

```
.google-visualization-table-tr-head-nonstrict {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    width: 600px !important;
    background-image: white !important;
}

.tableRowGoogle {
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
}

.headercellgoogle {
    padding: 6px;
    width: 150px;
}

.rowcellgoogle {
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.rowNumberCell {
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 15px;
}
```

and before drawing:

```
var options=null;
if(data.getNumberOfRows()>7){
    options = {
        width : 600,
        height:235,
        sort : 'enable',
        sortColumn : 1,
        sortAscending : false,
        scrollLeftStartPosition : 50,
        showRowNumber : true,
        chartArea : chartArea,
        cssClassNames : cssClassNames   
    };
}else{
    options = {
        width : 600,
        sort : 'enable',
        sortColumn : 1,
        sortAscending : false,
        scrollLeftStartPosition : 50,
        showRowNumber : true,
        chartArea : chartArea,
        cssClassNames : cssClassNames   
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across the answer.

adding background-color to

```
.headercellgoogle {
    padding: 6px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

within the css has fixed this issue